# Identify the ip to which an UDP port established connection

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

I'm trying to obtain the ip to which Rocketleague.exe has established connection on a UDP port. I've tried with netstat -p udp but for some strange reason it does not show any active udp connections . However, using TCPView, it does appear as using some UDP ports. The problem is that it does not show any ip address to which that specific port is connected. Here's a screenshot:

[image: capture]

as you can see it does not show the ip addresses to which the udp port has connected to, my questions are:

- is UDP more like a broadcast protocol and therefor my pc is only listening to that port for incoming information?
- if not, is there a way to identify the ip addresses to which those UDP ports are connected to?
- in case it is only listening and does not know from where te connections are comming, the ips from where the information is comming are the TCP ones to which the .exe is also connected?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `netstat` by default shows only connected sockets, and as answered UDP is connectionless, so you need `netstat -a -p udp` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is UDP more like a broadcast protocol and therefor my pc is only listening to that port for incoming information?

Not likely. UDP can be used that way, but it doesn't work very well over the Internet.

> if not, is there a way to identify the ip addresses to which those UDP ports are connected to?

UDP ports aren't connected to anything. UDP is connectionless.

> in case it is only listening and does not know from where te connections are comming, the ips from where the information is comming are the TCP ones to which the .exe is also connected?

There aren't connections as far as UDP is concerned. Each datagram sent or received has a source and a destination, but there's no persistent state related to that for you to look up.

Comment: You can **capture the packets** sent and/or received and look at them. Windows has some 'network tracing' builtin, but IMO http://www.wireshark.org is more convenient.

Comment: hadn't thought about that one, will try it out. Thanks a lot!